# Why does reading '2972 marks from 1 ranges' faster than reading '238 marks to read from 126 ranges' of the same data

Tags: clickhouse

I have the following table

```sql
CREATE TABLE slice (
    `uid` Int64,
    `start` DateTime64(3),
    ....
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toMonth(start)
ORDER BY (start, uid)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I need to select some slices within the given period of time by uids

```sql
SELECT uid, start, ...
FROM slice
WHERE start => '2021-12-23 00:00:00.000'
  AND start <  '2021-12-24 00:00:00.000'
  AND uid IN (...uids_list...)
```

`uids_list` contains hundreds of `uid`'s

Debug log says

```
(SelectExecutor): Selected 1 parts by partition key, 1 parts by primary key, 2972 marks by primary key, 2972 marks to read from 1 ranges
executeQuery: Read 24306405 rows, 405.29 MiB in 0.371851802 sec., 65365838 rows/sec., 1.06 GiB/sec.
```

About 1000 rows returned.
Ok, I added data skipping index to reduce amount of rows to read

```sql
ALTER TABLE slice ADD INDEX slice_uid_idx(uid) TYPE set(0) GRANULARITY 1;
```

Execution of the same query gives

```
(SelectExecutor): Index `slice_uid_idx` has dropped 2734 / 2972 granules.
(SelectExecutor): Selected 1 parts by partition key, 1 parts by primary key, 2972 marks by primary key, 238 marks to read from 126 ranges
executeQuery: Read 1948986 rows, 234.64 MiB in 1.328573644 sec., 1466976 rows/sec., 176.61 MiB/sec.
```

The questions are

1. Why has the request become slower: `0.37` vs `1.32` sec, despite of the fact that the number of read rows reduced from `24 306 405` to `1 948 986`
2. What does `range` mean in this case? (The number of ranges increased from `1` to `126`)

Comment: What kind of database? looks like mysql? what version?

Answer (score 1):

> PARTITION BY toMonth(start)

This is incorrect. You put data from different years into the same partition.
It should be `toYYYYMM(start)`

> `start` DateTime64(3)
> ORDER BY (start, uid)

This is incorrect. It has no sense to put anything to the second position after such high cardinal value as DateTime64(3).

Try to play with examples from here https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/33056

---

> ADD INDEX slice_uid_idx(uid) TYPE set(0) GRANULARITY 1

You just make CH to read the same data twice.

> TYPE set(0) GRANULARITY 1

It literally means take ALL data from the column `uid`, transform it from vertical structure into horizontal and put a result into skip_index.

Your skip index is harder to process than an original column. But after the index has been processed by SELECT query, a query also needs to read the column as well.

---

AFAIK `TYPE set(0)` has almost NO sense in general. In some very very rare cases it has sense for columns with low cardinality with index GRANULARITY >= 10.

---

For columns with high cardinality ( I am guessing from the column name `uid` ) it has sense to use bloom_filter skip index with GRANULARITY 2 / 4.

Comment: I've deleted the old skip index and added a new one of type `bloom_filter`. Query with the new index is still slower than without any skip indexes at all )
And what is `range` in the logs?

Comment: provide info how you created a bloom filter

Comment: `ALTER TABLE slice ADD INDEX slice_uid_idx(uid) TYPE bloom_filter GRANULARITY 4`

Comment: try `bloom_filter(0.1) granularity 10 or 50`

Comment: range - consecutive range of granules